# Convertion of 128-bit integer to string in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, system-calls

I am trying to convert an integer to string in order to output;
but I am using the x86_64 and `NASM` assembly while the integer is 128-bit, in two registers.
so I don't know how to output it;
Thanks!

Comment: i can't use C functions and don't know how to divide this long int in assembly

Comment: This question is already discussed, click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523530/printing-an-int-or-int-to-string). Isn't your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an (assembly-style) algorithm you can use for an unsigned integer. Start with the number `n`:

```
start:
    if n is non-zero then goto nonZeroNum.
    output '0'.
    return.

nonZeroNum:
    set digitCount to zero.
numLoop:
    get n modulo 10 and push it onto the stack.
    increment digitCount.
    divide n by 10 (integer division).
    if n is non-zero then goto numLoop.

digitLoop:
    pop digit.
    convert number to character (eg, adding 48 for ASCII).
    output that character.
    decrement digitCount.
    if digitCount is non-zero then goto digitLoop.
```

That should be a good start, I'd suggest running it through you wetware manually so that you understand how it works.

Then you simply need to work out the assembly instructions that will do what the pseudo-code does. That shouldn't be too onerous since it's likely to be a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: i know the way, but i don't know how to divide....For n is in two registers, but the instructions only deal with 64b/64b (I am not sure)

Comment: Instead of division you could use repeated subtraction. That's easy for any bit width. It also gives you the result in the correct order without having to mess with the stack ;)

Comment: Use the `DIV` (unsigned) or `IDIV` (signed) instruction depending on whether your 128-bit integer is unsigned or signed. You put the upper 64-bits into the `RDX` register and the lower 64-bits into the `RAX` register before the instruction. Then if you store 10 into `RBX` then the instruction `DIV   RBX` will divide by 10 and put the quotient into `RAX` and the remainder into `RDX` (writing over their original contents).

Comment: @pcarter, the problem is that if the quotient can't fit in RAX then you get a divide error. Try dividing 2^120 (a large value that fits in a 128-bit integer RDX:RAX) by 10. The quotient can't be represented in 64 bits and a divide error is generated.

Comment: thx to all of u, I may deal like this: divide n by 10^k, let 10^k < 2^64, then deal with the quotient and remainder separately, hope the num not too long ....in fact , the only reason is i am too lazy to write the algorithm