# Factorial of a number in nasm without recursion

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have made the following program for obtaining the factorial of a number:

```
section .data
    result_msg db 'Factorial: ', 0
    newline db 10

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Constants
    mov eax, 5      ; Number for which factorial is to be calculated

    ; Initialize result to 1
    mov ebx, 1      ; Result

    ; Loop to calculate factorial
    fact_loop:
        cmp eax, 1
        jle print_result

        ; Multiply current result by the current number
        imul ebx, eax

        ; Decrement the number
        dec eax

        jmp fact_loop

    print_result:
        ; Print "Factorial: "
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, result_msg
        mov edx, 10      ; Updated to the correct length of the message
        int 0x80

        ; Convert the result to ASCII and display it
        add ebx, '0'    ; Convert the result to ASCII
        mov eax, 4
        mov ecx, ebx    ; Use ebx directly as the result
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80

        ; Print newline
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        lea ecx, [newline]
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80

        ; Exit program
        mov eax, 1
        xor ebx, ebx
        int 0x80
```

The problem that I have is that it only prints the string "Factorial" but not 120. I am using the following online compiler:

https://rextester.com/l/nasm_online_compiler

What is missing in my solution?

Comment: https://rextester.com/l/nasm_online_compiler builds your code as x86-64, but its example starting point uses 32-bit `int 0x80` system calls.  That's bad.  Even worse, it doesn't appear to have a debugger to let you single-step and watch register values change, or even `strace` to decode system-call args and return values to see what you actually did.  That makes it nearly useless for learning asm, like trying to build a robot blindfolded.  https://www.onlinegdb.com/ is at least somewhat usable I think, if you don't want to get a dev environment set up locally, but only x86-64 GCC, not NASM.

Answer (score 0):

ebx contains an integer, not a pointer to a string, so it won't print correctly.  You'll need to convert the value in ebx to a string to print it, something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13523734/5938339.