MASM32, try to add two user's inputs, however I get letter from ADD
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data
    messageX db "Enter X: ", 0
    messageY db "Enter Y: ", 0
    messageR db "Result: ", 0
    x dword ?
    y dword ?
    r dword ?



.code

main:
    invoke StdOut, addr messageX
    push 50
    push offset x
    call StdIn
    invoke StdOut, addr messageY
    push 50
    push offset y
    call StdIn
    mov eax, x
    mov edx, y
    add edx, eax
    mov r, edx
    invoke StdOut, addr messageR
    push offset r
    call StdOut

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end main

Just started to work with assembly, StdIn gets correct numbers, but after I add them it changes to letter form, probobly hex or whatever. tried to look guides and other explanation, but they either use different commnads or don't show whole porcess

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523530/printing-an-int-or-int-to-string

show exactly the following: 1. what you input, 2. what you get, (and how you believe you go it,) and 3. what you expected instead.

For example I enter 2 for X and 3 for Y, expected to be 5, however I get 'e'

Note both your input and output are using ascii. You can simply subtract 48 which is the ascii code of 0 to fix it.

You have strings / characters that represent integer digits.  '2' + '3' is 0x32 + 0x33 = 0x65, the ASCII code for 'e'.  As @Jester says, ('2' - '0') + ('3'-'0') + '0' is '2' + '3' - '0'.  The x86 tag wiki (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has a link to an existing question about this problem (Why is my assembly output in letter position? (1+1=b)), and links to Q&As about how to handle multi-digit integers.

@Jester better to subtract '0'. The adjustment will be more tricky if their sum >= 10.

Thanks for answers, at least for 0 to 9 it works, will try to do for 10>= now

@DIlliy if the sum is > '9' then output '1', subtract 10 and output the units digit.

I can't post my answer if thread is closed, can I? Ok. I think x,y and maybe r too should be buffers for ascii digits not dwords because if user enters more than 2 chars StdIn adds 0x0d and 0x0a which will destroy memory area where those vars are located. I thought maybe we can use a2dw proc later to convert ascii strings to dwords but this code look buggy to me, like ecx should be 0 before while loop but it's not and value in eax is incorrect at the end.

For multi-digit numbers, see Displaying numbers with DOS / How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string) re: output, and NASM Assembly convert input to integer? re: input
